# Using XPathEvaluate with If Then Else

Tags: c#, xpath

I'm trying to get the result of an xPath expression in C#.

Here's the code :

```
const string xml = "<ROOT><NODE>VALUE1</NODE></ROOT>";
using (var textReader = new StringReader(xml))
{
     var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(textReader);
     var valueDate = xmlDoc.XPathEvaluate(@"if(boolean(//NAMEDNODE)) then //ANYNODE else //NODE ");
     Assert.IsNotNull(valueDate);
}
```

When I execute this code, I get an XPathException `invalid token`.

But when I test the xPath in an xPath tester, I get no error.

Do you have an idea about the reason?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XPath `if` expression was introduced in XPath 2.0, Microsoft never updated their XPath implementations to newer versions than the 20 year old XPath 1.0.

On the .NET platform however with .NET 2.0 the infrastructure for XPath 2.0 is there and if you add a third party XPath 2 implementation like https://www.nuget.org/packages/XPath2/ with https://www.nuget.org/packages/XPath2.Extensions/ then you can use XPath 2 expressions in the extension methods to the .NET APIs `XmlNode`, `XNode` and `XPathNavigator`.

For some reasons I don't understand https://github.com/StefH/XPath2.Net/blob/master/src/XPath2/Extensions/XNodeExtensions.cs provides various XPath2 related extensions to XNode but unfortunately no `xmlDoc.XPath2Evaluate` method, so in that case it seems you need to use `xmlDoc.CreateNavigator().XPath2Evaluate` to evaluate XPath 2 expression in general.

There are however several node selection related methods like `xmlDoc.XPath2Select` that should work in your case of `xmlDoc.XPath2Select("if(boolean(//NAMEDNODE)) then //ANYNODE else //NODE")`. As that methods returns an `IEnumerable` which is never null you might need to adapt your assertion to test `valueDate.Any()` is true.